# Passing a value from a Bootstrap Modal to a Button from which it is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

**What I want:**

I have many **buttons** and each button is attached to a **single bootstrap modal**. What I want is to get a value from the **bootstrap modal** each time the **confirm button** on the bootstrap modal is pressed and set the value of the button from which that particular modal is triggered or shown.

**My Buttons are like this:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete Medicine</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete Medicine</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete Medicine</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete Medicine</button>
```

**Any help with code samples would be highly appreciated?**

Answer (score 2):

Hope you this ans is helpful for  you,

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var attr_Id = $(this).attr('id').slice(3);
  var value_txt = $(this).text();
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#value" + attr_Id).text("");
  $("#value" + attr_Id).append("You select:"+value + ":" + value_txt + ":" + attr_Id);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btn1" value="button1">Open Modal</button>
    <label id=value1>You select:</label><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btn2" value="button2">Open Modal</button>
    <label id=value2>You select:</label>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have multiple buttons with the same class and what i want is to set the value of label in front of that particular button from which the modal is displayed? Can you edit this with multiple buttons/label with same class ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ7934J6VTON                                      reach out this it work in mozila and chrome too

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app.js you can can modify the value of the input button, assuming each button is as follows:

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="changeValues()">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am trying to get the from a modal